# Does not compare email correctly in exposed

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-exposed

There is a `saveUserInfo` method that checks if there is a user with such an email, but I log in with the same account and it creates an entry in the database for me every time, although it should not.

```
override suspend fun saveUserInfo(user: UserResponse): Boolean = withContext(dispatcher) {
        try {
            val existingUser = transaction {
                UserEntity.find { UserTable.emailAddress eq user.emailAddress }.singleOrNull()
            }

            if (existingUser == null) {
                logger.debug("User does not exist, creating a new one")
                transaction {
                    UserEntity.new {
                        name = user.name
                        emailAddress = user.emailAddress
                        profilePhoto = user.profilePhoto
                    }
                }
                logger.debug("User successfully created")
                true
            } else {
                logger.debug("User already exists")
                false
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            logger.error("Error in saveUserInfo: ${e.message}", e)
            false
        }
    }
```

Also here is logs[image]

And also here is the database entries
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`singleOrNull()` will return an element if there is exactly one, and `null` otherwise. As long as you already have more than one user with the same address in your database, this code will always create more new users.

This code doesn't show how the second user got created. My guess would be a bug in a previous version.

Comment: how can the problem be solved?
Remove just singleOrNull ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a unique constraint to the email address field. That'll make sure you never even get to this problem.

Comment: are you talking about uniqueIndex?